Bug on mobile - Interactive cards (HTML, CSS, JavaScript)
I am working on a card interface where the user can navigate between steps.
There is just one bug on mobile.
For example, when you click from step 1 to step 2, it works fine, but when you click from step 2 to step 3, it goes wrong. The third card is not fully visible on mobile.
When you click back from step 5 to step 1, the entire flow works perfectly. This is how it should also work when moving forward, but in the opposite direction, of course.
Can someone please help me with this on short notice?
It’s for a client’s website that needs to be finished quickly.
Bug on mobile

Element

I have tried to restructure the JavaScript, but unfortunately, my knowledge of JavaScript is limited, so I am unable to solve the problem.
My code:


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const container = document.querySelector('.container');

    function switchCard(targetCard) {
        let currentCard = document.querySelector('.bigCard');
        if (currentCard) {
            currentCard.classList.remove('bigCard');
            currentCard.classList.add('smallCard');

            let currentButton = currentCard.querySelector('.button');
            if (currentButton) {
                currentButton.classList.add('hidden');
            }

            let currentSecondText = currentCard.querySelector('.secondHeadText');
            if (currentSecondText) {
                currentSecondText.classList.add('hidden');
            }

            let currentPrevButton = currentCard.querySelector('.button.prev');
            if (currentPrevButton) {
                currentPrevButton.classList.add('hidden');
            }
        }

        targetCard.classList.remove('smallCard');
        targetCard.classList.add('bigCard');

        let targetButton = targetCard.querySelector('.button');
        if (targetButton) {
            targetButton.classList.remove('hidden');
        }

        let targetSecondText = targetCard.querySelector('.secondHeadText');
        if (targetSecondText) {
            targetSecondText.classList.remove('hidden');
        }

        let targetPrevButton = targetCard.querySelector('.button.prev');
        if (targetPrevButton) {
            targetPrevButton.classList.remove('hidden');
        }

        // Scroll naar de juiste positie
        const cardRect = targetCard.getBoundingClientRect();
        const containerRect = container.getBoundingClientRect();
        container.scrollLeft += cardRect.left - containerRect.left;
    }

    document.querySelectorAll('.smallCard, .bigCard').forEach(card => {
        card.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            if (event.target.classList.contains('button')) return;

            switchCard(this);
        });
    });

    document.querySelectorAll('.button').forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            let targetCardSelector = this.getAttribute('data-target');
            let targetPrevCardSelector = this.getAttribute('data-target-prev');
            let targetCard = document.querySelector(targetCardSelector);
            let targetPrevCard = document.querySelector(targetPrevCardSelector);

            if (this.classList.contains('prev')) {
                // Terug klikken
                if (targetPrevCard) {
                    switchCard(targetPrevCard);
                }
            } else {
                // Vooruit klikken
                if (targetCard) {
                    switchCard(targetCard);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
@media (max-width: 900px) {
    .container {
        display: flex;
        overflow-x: auto;
        scroll-snap-type: x mandatory; 
        width: 100vw; 
        padding: 0 20px; 
    }

    .cardContainer {
        scroll-snap-align: start; 
        flex: none; 
    }
    
    .cardContainer:first-child {
        margin-left: 20px;
    }

    .cardContainer:last-child {
        margin-right: 20px;
    }
}

.container::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

.container {
    -ms-overflow-style: none; 
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.cardContainer {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
    flex: 0 0 auto; 
}

a.button {
    background: lightgrey;
    padding: 15px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    line-height: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
}

a.button.prevRight {
    bottom: 20px !important;
    right: 20px !important;
}

a.button.prev {
    right: 80px;
}

.button.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.smallCard, .bigCard {
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: black;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.smallCard {
    height: 330px;
    width: 100px;
}

.smallCard:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.smallCard h1 {
    padding-top: 15px;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.smallCard p {
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    white-space: nowrap;
    line-height: 140px;
}

.smallCard .secondHeadText {
    display: none;
}

.bigCard {
    height: 330px;
    width: 330px;
}

.bigCard p.headText {
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.bigCard p.secondHeadText {
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.bigCard h1 {
    padding-top: 30px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin: 0;
}

.bigCard p {
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin: 0;
}
.bigCard:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}
<section class="container">
    <div class="cardContainer">
        <div class="bigCard" id="card1">
            <h1>01.</h1>
            <p class="headText">Kies het Type Dienst</p>
            <p class="secondHeadText">Hier moet een informatie tekst komen die verdere informatie geeft over deze specifieke stap. (van max 4 regels).
            <a class="button" href="#" data-target="#card2">></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="cardContainer">
        <div class="smallCard" id="card2">
            <h1>02.</h1>
            <p class="headText">Vul Gebouwgegevens in</p>
            <p class="secondHeadText">Hier moet een informatie tekst komen die verdere informatie geeft over deze specifieke stap. (van max 4 regels).
            <a class="button hidden" href="#" data-target="#card3">></a>
            <a class="button prev hidden" href="#" data-target-prev="#card1"><</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="cardContainer">
        <div class="smallCard" id="card3">
            <h1>03.</h1>
            <p class="headText">Voer contactgegevens in</p>
            <p class="secondHeadText">Hier moet een informatie tekst komen die verdere informatie geeft over deze specifieke stap. (van max 4 regels).
            <a class="button hidden" href="#" data-target="#card4">></a>
            <a class="button prev hidden" href="#" data-target-prev="#card2"><</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="cardContainer">
        <div class="smallCard" id="card4">
            <h1>04.</h1>
            <p class="headText">Verzend de aanvraag</p>
            <p class="secondHeadText">Hier moet een informatie tekst komen die verdere informatie geeft over deze specifieke stap. (van max 4 regels).
            <a class="button hidden" href="#" data-target="#card5">></a>
            <a class="button prev hidden" href="#" data-target-prev="#card3"><</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="cardContainer">
        <div class="smallCard" id="card5">
            <h1>05.</h1>
            <p class="headText">Offerte terug binnen 24u</p>
            <p class="secondHeadText">Hier moet een informatie tekst komen die verdere informatie geeft over deze specifieke stap. (van max 4 regels).
            <a class="button prev prevRight hidden" href="#" data-target-prev="#card4"><</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>




When I test it, using device emulation in Firefox, it sort of seems to work. What exact device and browser are you using to test your code?

Iphone 12 and in Safari
